# Vue: Using material-design-icons offline / size

Tags: vue.js, svg, npm, vuetify.js, material-design-icons

I am using materialdesignicons in my vue project.

```
require ('../node_modules/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css);
Vue.use(Vuetify, {iconfont:'mdi'});
```

I have a handful of icons which I dynamically create:

```
 <v-icon>{{ some-mdi-file }}</v-icon>
```

When I build for production via (npm run build) I get the following error:

```
asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  img/materialdesignicons-webfont.someHash.svg (3.77 MiB)
```

That file size is huge because it includes every icon, regardless of whether it's being used. Is there a way to trim that file size down by only packaging the specific icons used. Is there a different package I should be using? Caveat: The project is hosted offline, so I need to include the fonts directly in my project.

I looked at vue-material-design-icons but it looks like it may not work for dynamic icon names and it says nothing about the overall file size/performance.

I have also looked here but clicking on the 'size warning' link brings me to a page where the Vue portion is not filled out
https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/getting-started/webfont

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using the [@mdi/js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mdi/js) package for this which provides SVG paths for each icon and supports tree shaking. Currently Vuetify doesn't support SVG icons but [it should in the future](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4340).

For now, it's easy enough to create a custom icon component:

```
<template>
    <svg :class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path :d="path" />
    </svg>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'my-icon',

    data: () => ({
        path: '',
    }),

    methods: {
        updatePath() {
            if (!this.$scopedSlots) return
            if (typeof this.$scopedSlots.default !== 'function') return

            this.path = this.$scopedSlots
                .default()
                .map((n) => n.text)
                .join('')
        },
    },

    mounted() {
        this.updatePath()
    },

    updated() {
        this.updatePath()
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.icon {
    display: block;
    color: inherit;
    fill: currentColor;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
<style>
```

Then to use it you just need to import your component and the icon you want to use:

```
<template>
    <div class="app">
        <my-icon>{{mdiCheck}}</my-icon>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyIcon from 'path/to/my/icon.vue'
import { mdiCheck } from '@mdi/js'

export default {
    name: 'my-app',

    components: {
        MyIcon,
    }

    data: () => ({
        mdiCheck,
    }),
}
</script>
```